# How can I create a video from a directory of images in C

Tags: c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, jnienv

How can I create a video from directory which contain set of images using c language. I want to do this inside a c Class file (not in command prompt). Something similar to this.

```
void ImagetoVideo(char [] path)
{
   // create video from file
}
```

I saw some code in the stack overflow but it's all about running a command line code.
This is the code

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number n -i "PATH_TO_IMAGE_FILE" video.mpg 
    -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not that simple. FFMpeg is a huge universal media transcoder tool, and it was hard and long to write (may I say "one does not simply implement `ImageToVideo()` in 24 LOC"?)...

Comment: You could invoke that command line from your program, so why do you want/need to do it the hard way?

Comment: @wetson How can I invoke that command line inside my program ? That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could code it yourself, it's not too difficult.

For AVI encoding you can use [Revel](http://revel.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html). For JPG image processing you can use [libJPEG](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/). If you have images in other format you can use apropriate library to read them.

The full code to read every image and encode it would be a bit long. So, I show you the idea using pseudo-code. I used the same way when had a similar task.

```
   #include "revel.h"
    extern "C" {
     #include "libjpeg/jpeglib.h"
    }

    std::vector<BYTE> frame_buffer;

    Revel_Error revError;
    int encoderHandle;
    revError = Revel_CreateEncoder(&encoderHandle);
    Revel_Params revParams;
    Revel_InitializeParams(&revParams);

    revParams.width = ; // put image width here
    revParams.height = ; // put image height here
//
    revParams.frameRate = 25;
    revParams.quality = 1.0f;
    revParams.codec = REVEL_CD_XVID;
    revParams.hasAudio = 0;
    revParams.audioSampleFormat = REVEL_ASF_UNKNOWN;
    char favi[] = "encoded_video.avi";
    revError = Revel_EncodeStart(encoderHandle, favi, &revParams);

while(read & decode every image into 'frame_buffer' with apropriate lib)
{
    Revel_VideoFrame frame;
    frame.width = image.getwidth();
    frame.height = image.getheight();
    frame.bytesPerPixel = ; // color depth in bytes. if you're using libjpeg it would be cinfo.num_components;
    frame.pixelFormat = REVEL_PF_BGR;
    frame.pixels = &frame_buffer[0];
    int frameSize;
    revError = Revel_EncodeFrame(encoderHandle, &frame, &frameSize);
}

    int totalSize;
    revError = Revel_EncodeEnd(encoderHandle, &totalSize);
    Revel_DestroyEncoder(encoderHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command inside your C++ (or C) code by using:
system(...);

Here's more info: [system(..)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

Comment: `exec()` would probably be more appropriate